# Why won't two subscriptions to an observable without shareReplay() execute code twice?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I was trying to figure out RxJs. ShareReplay operator in particular. As per my understanding if there are two subscriptions to an observable then the observable should be executed twice. Unless there is a shareReplay involved. Obviously my understanding is incorrect because that is not what I is happening here. Could someone please help me understand this?

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
      constructor() {}
      i = 0;
      ngOnInit() {
        console.clear();
        let ob = this.httpcall().pipe(map(d => d));
        let ob1$ = ob.pipe(map(d => d.toUpperCase()));
        let ob2$ = ob.pipe(map(d => d.toLowerCase()));

        ob1$.subscribe(d => {
          console.log(d);
        });
        ob2$.subscribe(d => {
          console.log(d);
        });
      }

      httpcall() {
        console.log("called");
        this.i++;
        return of("server cAlled:" + this.i);
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
called
 SERVER CALLED:1
 server called:1
```

The counter i did not get incremented to two even though there are two subscriptions and no shareReplay involved.

**I was expecting(without shareReplay):**

```
 called
 SERVER CALLED:1
 called
 server called:2
```

**And with `let ob = this.httpcall().pipe(map(d=>d),shareReplay());` I was expecting:**

```
 called
 SERVER CALLED:1
 server called:1
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call subscribe, that will cause the observable to do everything it was defined to do. It was defined using `of("server cAlled: 1");`, which is then passed into a map operator. So since you subscribed twice, `of` will do its thing twice, and `map` will do its thing twice.

You happened to create the observable inside a function named httpcall, but the observable doesn't know anything about httpcall. httpcall will not be invoked an additional time.

If you want the incrementing of this.i to be part of what happens when subscribing, then you may need to use Observable.create. For example:

```
httpcall() {
  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    this.i++;
    observer.next("server called: " + this.i);
    observer.complete();
  })
}
```

Comment: You say `since you subscribed twice, of will do its thing twice,` then how come counter did not turn 2?

Comment: Because you called `of("server cAlled: 1");`. When the second subscribe happens, `of` emits "server cAlled: 1", since that's what it was asked to do. `of` has no idea how you created that string, and since you're not calling httpcall again, no new string will get created.

Comment: So you are saying its because i++ is not a part of observable and therefore it wont be executed twice? So in a way if I say `ob1$.subscribe()` twice I am not calling httpcall() not even a single time,  I am just calling/executing `of("serVer cAlled:" + this.i)` twice ?

Comment: Correct. `i++` is part of `httpcall`. Subscribing will do everything that's defined by the chain of observables, but nothing in the observable chain is even aware that `httpcall` or `i` exist. So httpcall is not run, this.i is not incremented, and no new string is created.

Comment: OK, I think I am getting it now.. but I am still not sure what difference would `shareReplay` make in this example. Because as of now I see no difference in the result (with or without shareReplay)

Comment: In your example, it makes very little difference, since there are no side effects in the observable. If you added a `tap` with a log statement, you'd see that the tap is not being rerun when shareReplay is used. This indirectly points out that the `map` and `of` are not being rerun either. If instead the observable does have side effects -- such as my modified example with i++ in `Observable.create`, or in `http.get` -- then the difference is more important, because you (probably) don't want those side effects to happen multiple times.

Comment: Just when I thought I have understood it, I have gotten more confused.
You said that in my example `of()` will do its thing twice if I subscribe twice.
So I changed my code to `return of("serVer cAlled:" + this.i++);` and subscribed to `ob1$` twice and the counter is `0 both the times??` Should it not be 1 the first time and 2 the second time ?

Comment: All that `of` knows is that it was passed a string. Whatever that string is, it will emit that string, forever. If you pass in "foo", then on every subscription, it will emit "foo". If you pass in "semVer cAlled: 0"  (which you did), then on every subscription it will emit "semVer cAlled: 0". It has no idea how that string was constructed.

Comment: Not even when the evaluation of i is happening within the of()? `of()` is a weird observable. `return of( this.i++)`

Comment: When you do `console.log('hello ' + 0)`, javascript starts by evaluating `'hello ' + 0`, and produces the string `'hello 0'`. Now that it knows that value, it can call console.log, passing in `'hello 0'`. When you do `of('semVer cAlled: ' + 0)`, it's the same thing. Javascript first concatenates the strings, then passes a string in. Changing the `0` to a `this.i++` just adds one more step to the calculation, but this calculation is still done *before* `of` is called. `of` only gets passed in a string. This isn't something special about `of`, it's about order of operations in javascript.

Comment: Got it! it's because its i++ and not ++i. 
The only thing that I have still not be able to wrap by head around is `shareReplay` part. You are not obliged to make me understand this. I am a beginner in javascript. I appreciate the help. Really. +1.

Comment: May be I should post a separate question for shareReplay?

Answer (score 0):

it seems that of return observable of it's own, so it's body doesn't get executed twice, so i recreate the example to show the difference between normal observable and of

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
  ) {
  }

  i = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.clear();
    const ob = this.httpCall1();
    const ob1$ = ob.pipe(map(d => d.toUpperCase()));
    const ob2$ = ob.pipe(map(d => d.toLowerCase()));

    ob1$.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d);
    });
    ob2$.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d);
    });

    this.i = 0;

    const ob2 = this.httpCall2();
    const ob3$ = ob2.pipe(map(d => d.toUpperCase()));
    const ob4$ = ob2.pipe(map(d => d.toLowerCase()));

    ob3$.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d);
    });
    ob4$.subscribe(d => {
      console.log(d);
    });
  }

  httpCall1() {
    return of('server1 called:' + ++this.i).pipe(
      tap(d => console.log('tap1', d)),
    );
  }

  httpCall2() {
    return new Observable<string>((observer) => {
      this.i++;
      observer.next('server2 called: ' + this.i);
      observer.complete();
    }).pipe(
      tap(d => console.log('tap2', d)),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Dear God. RxJs could be so intimidating for beginners. I thought of() is just a convenient way of creating observable. Forget twice I don't think of() has executed even once the way i had expected. I mean even when i have `of("serVer cAlled:" + this.i++)` I get `SERVER CALLED:0` and not 1. Its like it has totally ignored ++

Comment: The reason you're getting 0 and not 1 is because of the way ++ works. If ++ is in postfix position (ie, `this.i++`) that means "return this.i, then increment this.i". You need to put it into prefix position (ie, `++this.i`) if you want the increment to happen first. Confusing behavior to be sure, but unrelated to RxJS.

Comment: of is a way to generate a sync observable, so it make a bit sense why it doesn't execute the body twice,
on the other hand new Observable is a way to make complex observable which can return more than one value, or to return error, so of is very limited compared to new Observable

Answer (score 0):

That is because `httpcall()` is called only once via following line `let ob = this.httpcall().pipe(map(d => d));`. So it means that `Observable` that is returned by `httpcall()` will be reused thereafter.

If thats clear, now think about `ob`, which is source Observable. If you subscribe to this Observable you are going to get `of("server cAlled:" + this.i);` where `this.i = 1`. `this.i` is only going to increase if method `httpcall()` is executed once more, but it is not. **Instead you are subscribing to the cold Observable `ob` which will just print what was used to create it.** The value of `this.i` (which equals to 1) is already stored inside Observable `ob` and it is not going to be changed until new instance is created, no matter how many times you subscribe to `ob`.

---

**Now lets look at the following code which is different:**

```
    let ob1$ = this.httpcall().pipe(map(d => d)).pipe(map(d => d.toUpperCase()));
    let ob2$ = this.httpcall().pipe(map(d => d)).pipe(map(d => d.toLowerCase()));
```

In this situation `httpcall()` is called twice, thus `this.i++;` would happen twice and you would get what you were thinking to get.